# Where can I find a good source for invisible strike

Tags: punching, striking

As can be seen in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mf2ua6PGdk) there are invisible strikes. I would like to know where can I find more like those. In addition, I would like to know what is the idea and the tricks that stand beyond the invisible strikes?

Comment: This is marketing stuff from a fat out-of-shape guy with compliant partners. The idea regarding real fighting is not "invisibility", but not telegraphing and using basic mechanics of the human ability to see movements. Also, this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdPP0TmqKiU

Comment: As well a telegraphing & perception aspects Philip mentions, you may want to search for "broken rhythm" - the ideas that by varying the timing, angles, patterns and level of commitment/power of your strikes it's harder for your opponent to consistently be tensed to receive them (which your "invisible strike" video mentions is the aim of striking suddenly rather than letting the opponent tense up).  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-MaAq46VHU) is illustrative.

Comment: Here is a great demonstration of an invisible energy attack, although I'm not knowledgeable of the technique myself: https://youtu.be/9QEHZ2yccco?t=122

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "invisible strike" is not martial arts, it is acting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff shown in the video is nonsense that only works because of auto-suggestion or a kind of hypnosis. These students are not just moving in an accommodating, compliant way. They have been "programmed" (hypnotized essentially) to feel as if a powerful, invisible force is being used against themselves. It won't work on people who aren't that guy's students.

There are lots of examples of this happening in martial arts. Some would even go so far as to say it's cult-like. I get sick of seeing it. And my heart goes out to anyone who has been suckered into believing in this stuff. None of it is real. It's all in your head. And it's completely unreliable for martial arts. I just wish the martial arts community would spread the word and make sure to smack this down wherever and whenever it comes up again.

Hope that helps.